Deriving integrated rate law for all concentrations

Given that


$$A ⟶ 2B$$ (0th order reaction with rate constant k0) and
$$B ⟶ C + 2D$$ (1st order reaction with rate constant k1)


Derive the integrated rate law for all concentrations [A]t, [B]t, [C]t, [D]t at any time t. Given that initial concentrations of A, B, C, and D are [A]0, 0, 0, 0 respectively.

I tried solving this problem by first integrating $d[A]/dt$ and got that
[A]t = [A]0 - k0t like normal 0th order reaction but with $d[B]/dt$, I got a function that does not depend on [A]0 and does not reach a maxima. Here's my work:
(Blue graph is [B]t, red graph is [A]t
How to correctly set up and derive integrated rate law for [B]t? Thank you so much.

Formatting guides for chemical/mathematical formulas/expressions/equations: Basics // Detailed // Upright vs Italics // Math SE Mathjax tutorial
// Not to be used in CH SE Q titles.

The rate expression for $[\ce{B}]$ will be the sum of rate expressions from 1st and 2nd reactions.
Thus rate law for different species is,
$$\begin{align}
\frac{\text{d}[\ce{A}]}{\text{d}t}&=-k_0\\
\frac{\text{d}[\ce{B}]}{\text{d}t}&=2k_0-k_1[\ce{B}]\\
\frac{\text{d}[\ce{C}]}{\text{d}t}&=k_1[\ce{B}]\\
\frac{\text{d}[\ce{D}]}{\text{d}t}&=2k_1[\ce{B}]
\end{align}$$
Solving these differential equations,
$$
[\ce{A}]=[\ce{A}]_0-k_0t
$$
and for $[\ce{B}]$,
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{[\ce{B}]}{\frac{1}{k_1[\ce{B}]-2k_0}}\text{d}t&=-\int_0^t{\text{d}t}\\
\frac{1}{k_1}\ln(k_1[\ce{B}]-2k_0)_0^{[\ce{B}]}&=-t\\
\ln\left(\frac{k_1[\ce{B}]-2k_0}{2k_0}\right)&=-k_1t\\
\frac{k_1}{2k_0}[\ce{B}]-1&=e^{-k_1t}\\
[\ce{B}]&=\frac{2k_0}{k_1}\left(1+e^{-k_1t}\right)
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$

[B]0 = 0, but your last equation suggests the opposite.

I think there might be a minor mistake in the integration  $$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{[\ce{B}]}{\frac{1}{2k_0-k_1[\ce{B}]}}\text{d}t&=\int_0^t{\text{d}t}\
-\frac{1}{k_1}\ln(2k_0 - k_1[\ce{B}])_0^{[\ce{B}]}&= t\  \frac{1}{k_1}\ln(2k_0 - k_1[\ce{B}])_0^{[\ce{B}]}&= -t\
\ln\left(\frac{2k_0 - k_1[\ce{B}]}{2k_0}\right)&=-k_1t\
1- \frac{k_1}{2k_0}[\ce{B}]&=e^{-k_1t}\
[\ce{B}]&=\frac{2k_0}{k_1}\left(1-e^{-k_1t}\right)
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$

At long times $B\to 0$ because A can only be positive. Thus after $t \ge A_0/k_0$ when $A=0$,  B decays by a first order process. Thus your solution should only apply up to time $A_0/k_0$ after which B decays exponentially with rate constant $k_1$

@porphyrin I agree. This is a consecutive reaction and the concentration of B should decrease as $t \rightarrow \infty$, but the equation predicts that the concentration reaches a maximum. There must be something essetially mistaken but I can not see it.

@PEAP the kinetics change when A becomes zero as then any remaining B can only decay by first order kinetics

@porphyrin Thanks. So simple it is a bit embarrassing not having noticed it.

@PEAP No need to feel embarrassed at all :)
